# My ajax function isnt sending the data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-maps

First of all Im working with google maps and im using tomcat
and what im trying to do is that when i click on the map, I place a marker and
at the same moment y send the lat and long of the point

Here's my code:

```
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event)
    {
            placeMarker(event.latLng);
            $.ajax({
                url: 'insertPoint.java',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {lat:latitud, lon:longitud},
                dataType: 'json',
                cache: false
            })
             .done(function(mensaje) {

                 document.write("success");
             })
             .error(function(mensaje) {
                 document.write("error");
             });
    });
    }
```

But I dont know why i always get error.
If You need something else I will edit the post and post what you guys need

Thanks

PD: i have also tried to change the url line into this:

```
url: 'insertPoint',
```

Comment: Have you checked your browsers console for any error reports?

Comment: just like the console tab what do you see in the network tab against the url that you fire...that will answer your query.

Comment: `send the lat and long of the point` - how do you think you're doing that?  `{lat:latitud, lon:longitud}` - what are latitud and longitud ?

Comment: _But I dont know why i always get error_ and yet you say _0 error reports_

Comment: Jaromanda X because i do a document.write if the ajax doesnt sends the info, if it sends it, it says success, latitud and longitud are variables

Comment: don't do document write for a start unless you understand the full consequences of doing so ... how are these variables set? also, in the error code console.log(mensaje) - then you'll see what the error is

Comment: okok i'll remove the document.write. var latitud;
            var longitud;

Answer (score 0):

jQuery promice doesnt have the `error` method. You need to listen errors with the `fail` method

```
 .fail(function(error){})
```

Answer (score 0):

ajax POST should call in this format.

```
   $.ajax({
          url: 'url',
          type: 'post',
          data: {'lat':latitud, 'lon':longitud},
          dataType: 'json',
          cache: false,
          success: function(result){
              alert('success!');
          },
          failed: function(result){
              alert('Somethings wrong');
          }
    });
```